# Set dynamic height value to dataRowHeight Property of DataTable Widget to fit different Row's content - #flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, material-components-android, flutter-table

I need to set dynamic height value to dataRowHeight property of DataTable Widget to fit different Row's contents and I don't want to use Table Widget which allows that. - #flutter

As by default, it uses kMinInteractiveDimension value of (48.0) as defined in DataTableThemeData.

```
DataTable(dataRowHeight: 150, columns: [DataColumn()...], rows: [DataRow()....])
```

Check this image:
[image]